# SQL Query to do an INNER JOIN based on 3 different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Initially, let me describe what I want my query to return.  I want this query to return all of the records from the Address table which have an AddressTypeLookupID of either 3 or 5, which is set in the AddressType table.  Second, as a further restriction, this must also include only companies with IndustryTypeID = 56, which is set in the IndustryType table.  All records in the Address, AddressType, and IndustryType tables are linked by ID.

```
SELECT B.AddressTypeLookupID, A.Address1, A.Address2, A.City, A.State, A.Zip, A.ID
FROM Company.dbo.Address A 
INNER JOIN Company.dbo.AddressType B ON A.AddressID = B.AddressID
WHERE B.Status = 'Active' AND
      B.AddressTypeLookupID = 3 AND
      A.AddressID = (SELECT MAX(Z.AddressID) 
                    FROM Company.dbo.Address Z 
                      INNER JOIN Company.dbo.AddressType X ON Z.AddressID = X.AddressID
                    WHERE B.Status = 'Active' 
                      AND B.AddressTypeLookupID = 3 
                      AND Z.ID = A.ID
                    )
INNER JOIN COMPANY.dbo.IndustryTypeCompanyName g ON g.ID = A.ID
WHERE g.IndustryTypeID = 56

UNION ALL

SELECT B.AddressTypeLookupID, A.Address1, A.Address2, A.City, A.State, A.Zip, A.ID
FROM Company.dbo.Address A 
INNER JOIN Company.dbo.AddressType B ON A.AddressID = B.AddressID
WHERE B.Status = 'Active' AND
      B.AddressTypeLookupID = 5  AND
      A.AddressID = (SELECT MAX(Z.AddressID)
                  FROM Company.dbo.Address Z 
                  INNER JOIN Company.dbo.AddressType X ON Z.AddressID = X.AddressID
                  WHERE B.Status = 'Active' AND
                        B.AddressTypeLookupID = 5 AND
                        Z.ID = A.ID                        
                  )
INNER JOIN COMPANY.dbo.IndustryTypeCompanyName j ON j.ID = A.ID
WHERE j.IndustryTypeID = 56
```

My issue is, I believe, with the inner joins called 'g' and 'j' above, where I try to restrict the query by `IndustryTypeID = 56`.  The query works properly (as desired) without these lines.  I am simply having trouble restricting the (full) query by `IndustryTypeID` to be 56.  I either am wrong in my logic, am or I simply not understanding SQL syntax.  I am using Microsoft SQL Management Studio 2008.

Comment: What isn't working?  Are you getting no rows with the current query?  Are you sure that there are any addresses with an IndustryTypeId of 56?

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned that: I am actually getting a syntax error: "Syntax error near INNER".  Helpful, isn't it.  But we know it is from the 'g' or 'j' join clauses since it works properly without these.

Comment: Remove that subQuery to determine `AddressID` that's gonna severely affect performance. Just Declare a variable  Set @variable = "query", then `A.AddressID = @variable`

Comment: I am reading through and carefully considering all answers below, I haven't abandoned this question or anything just caught up with other work at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the last join is supposed to mean, but as far as I can tell your query can be simplified to:

```
SELECT B.AddressTypeLookupID, A.Address1, A.Address2, A.City, A.State, A.Zip, A.ID
FROM Company.dbo.Address A 
JOIN Company.dbo.AddressType B 
    ON A.AddressID = B.AddressID
JOIN COMPANY.dbo.IndustryTypeCompanyName g 
    ON g.ID = A.ID
WHERE B.Status = 'Active' 
  AND B.AddressTypeLookupID in (3,5) 
  AND A.AddressID = ( SELECT MAX(Z.AddressID) 
                      FROM Company.dbo.Address Z 
                      JOIN Company.dbo.AddressType X 
                          ON Z.AddressID = X.AddressID
                      WHERE 
                      -- redundant predicates removed
                      -- B.Status = 'Active' 
                      -- AND B.AddressTypeLookupID = 3 
                      -- AND 
                             Z.ID = A.ID
                    )          
  AND g.IndustryTypeID = 56
```

Answer (score 1):

I see the issue now that we know it is a syntax error.  You have an inner join, a where, then another inner join, then another where.  Each group can only occur once in the requried order, but you can use the keyword join more than once.  So select, from, join, join where.

```
SELECT B.AddressTypeLookupID, A.Address1, A.Address2, A.City, A.State, A.Zip, A.ID
FROM Company.dbo.Address A
INNER JOIN Company.dbo.AddressType B
ON A.AddressID = B.AddressID
INNER JOIN COMPANY.dbo.IndustryTypeCompanyName g
ON g.ID                   = A.ID
WHERE B.Status            = 'Active'
AND B.AddressTypeLookupID = 3
AND A.AddressID           =
  (SELECT MAX(Z.AddressID)
  FROM Company.dbo.Address Z
  INNER JOIN Company.dbo.AddressType X
  ON Z.AddressID            = X.AddressID
  WHERE B.Status            = 'Active'
  AND B.AddressTypeLookupID = 3
  AND Z.ID                  = A.ID
  )
AND g.IndustryTypeID = 56
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your already including the address table in your select rather than selecting max it would be easier to just use ROW_NUMBER() to solve your 1 per group problem

```
With cte as
(
    SELECT B.addresstypelookupid, 
           A.address1, 
           A.address2, 
           A.city, 
           A.state, 
           A.zip, 
           A.id ,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER  (Partition BY b.addresstypelookupid  
                               order by addressid desc  )  rn
    FROM   company.dbo.address A 
           INNER JOIN company.dbo.addresstype B 
                   ON A.addressid = B.addressid 
                      AND B.addresstypelookupid IN ( 3, 5 ) 
                      AND B.status = 'Active' 
           INNER JOIN company.dbo.industrytypecompanyname g 
                   ON g.id = A.id 
    WHERE  g.industrytypeid = 56 
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE Rn = 1
```